# Diamondback's image_transport fails to compile, how come?

Tags: ros, boost, image-transport, archlinux, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am compiling ROS Diamondback from source, following the instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Arch. Most of the packages,
especially core ones like `roscpp` compile without any problems, but when compiling image_transport via

```
rosmake image_transport
```

I receive the following error, where

```
  [ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/image_transport.dir/src/publisher.o
  In file included from /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/detail/reversible_ptr_container.hpp:24:0,
                   from /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/ptr_sequence_adapter.hpp:20,
                   from /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp:20,
                   from /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/src/publisher.cpp:38:
/usr/include/boost/ptr_container/clone_allocator.hpp:
[...] lots of other compiler error output [...]
 /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/src/publisher.cpp:59:5:   instantiated from here
  /usr/include/boost/ptr_container/clone_allocator.hpp:34:27: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘image_transport::PublisherPlugin’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:13:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘image_transport::PublisherPlugin’:
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:22:23: note:     virtual std::string image_transport::PublisherPlugin::getTransportName() const
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:49:20: note:     virtual uint32_t image_transport::PublisherPlugin::getNumSubscribers() const
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:54:23: note:     virtual std::string image_transport::PublisherPlugin::getTopic() const
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:59:16: note:     virtual void image_transport::PublisherPlugin::publish(const Image&) const
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:72:16: note:     virtual void image_transport::PublisherPlugin::shutdown()
  /opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/include/image_transport/publisher_plugin.h:87:16: note:     virtual void image_transport::PublisherPlugin::advertiseImpl(ros::NodeHandle&, const string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const VoidPtr&, bool)
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_transport.dir/src/publisher.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_transport.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/diamondback/image_common/image_transport/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package image_transport written to:
```

The compiler doesn't like line 59 in image_transport/src/publishers.cpp

```
 56   uint32_t getNumSubscribers() const
 57   {
 58     uint32_t count = 0;
 59     BOOST_FOREACH(const PublisherPlugin& pub, publishers_)
 60       count += pub.getNumSubscribers();
 61     return count;
 62   }
 63
```

This very much seems like some piece of code trying to instantiate an abstract class that
contains pure virtual methods (=0). Yet, I expect Diamondback's source tag to compile and be consistent. Is it possible that this is symptom of an incompatibility of ROS diamondback with a certain Boost version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10943/diamondback%27s-image_transport-fails-to-compile,-how-come?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-08-18**:
I am using boost version 1.47.0-1. I might try to use version 1.40 then, thanks! If that doesn't work out, of course, I'll move to Ubuntu for ROS development. I am fully aware that Arch support is experimental.

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-08-18**:
What version of Boost are you using? Our target platforms are specified in http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html. For Diamondback we expect 1.40, but I'd expect at least as far back as 1.37 (C Turtle) to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Diamondback's pluginlib (image_transport depends on pluginlib) compiles with Boost 1.43,0-1  but not with Boost 1.47.01 on Arch. Use Arch Rollback Machine to downgrade to older version of Boost to solve this issue (thanks Patrick for this link:  http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it to compile by changing the offending BOOST_FOREACH into a regular for loop.

for ( uint32_t i = 0 ; i 


---

Originally posted by [gleechinese](https://answers.ros.org/users/1057/gleechinese/) with karma: 96 on 2011-10-10


This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4